# How is Bad-Tibira written in Sumerian?

Tags: language, mesopotamia, sumer

[Bad-Tibira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad-tibira) is one of the oldest recorded cities in the world.  The Sumerians believed it was the second city to exercise kingship (after the more famous Eridu).  I can't find the Sumerian spelling of the name anywhere.  I'm looking for two things:

- the Sumerian cuneiform spelling of Bad-Tibira
- a Romanized transcription of the Sumerian

---

I think this is probably on-topic for here, but if not, that's a shame, since there's probably never going to be a [sumerian.stackexchange.com](http://sumerian.stackexchange.com) to ask it on.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this syllabary of Sumerian](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/sumerian.htm), and just how one wishes to pronounce **Bad-Tibira**, one possible Sumerian transcription is this:

[image]

Whether this is also an accurate transcription of "Fortress of the Copper-Smiths" I cannot say.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ETCSL](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/edition2/etcslgloss.php?lookup=c407a.34&charenc=gcirc) Sign names and embedding texts are also shown on this site.